# JavaFx button set Text with Timer task

Tags: java, javafx

Hi im having a weird problem with my `button.setText()` method.
I checked the Timeline class and Service which are Java8 specific but with no win.

I am trying to update the button (which is responsible for updating the app with the files from the remote) with the countdown message `"Updated. Restarting in 5,4,3,2,1 seconds..."`

After i click the button i got a Vbox with release notes and 2 buttons inside `Update/Cancel`

The code for Vbox buttons is:

```
final Button updateButton = new Button("Update");
      updateButton.setOnAction(update -> {
         new UpdateChecker().update();

                    restartStopwatch(mainUpdateButton);

                    mainUpdateButton.setDisable(true);
                    dialog.close();
                });

                final Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
                cancelButton.setOnAction(close -> dialog.close());
```

Then the restartStopwatch code :

```
private void restartStopwatch(Button button) {

    final Timer restartTimer = new Timer();
    final TimerTask updateRestartTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        int time = 5;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            button.setText("Updated. Restarting in: " + time + " Seconds...");
            time--;
            if (time <= 0) {
                restartTimer.cancel();
                new UpdateChecker().restartApplication();
            }
        }
    };
    restartTimer.schedule(updateRestartTimerTask, 0, 1000);
}
```

The weird part comes when i do `button.setText("anything");` as a first thing in the `private void restartStopwatch(Button button)` then the button is being set to `Updated. Restarting in 5 seconds...` and it doesn't countdown but if i don't set the `button.setText("sfrhgd)` to anything as a first thing in the method it does not set it at all.

It doesn't give any exception either. I have been reading about, some threads cant access JavaFx stuff but I cant find the solution. I hope i Explained it close enough.

The whole code looks like this:

```
mainUpdateButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                final Stage dialog = new Stage();
                dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                dialog.initOwner(stage);
                dialog.setResizable(false);
                VBox dialogVbox = new VBox(20);
                String releaseNotes = IOUtils.toString(new FileReader(new File("ReleaseNotes.txt")));
                dialogVbox.getChildren().add(new Text(releaseNotes));

                final Button updateButton = new Button("Update");
                updateButton.setOnAction(update -> {
                    new UpdateChecker().update();

                    restartStopwatch(mainUpdateButton);

                    mainUpdateButton.setDisable(true);
                    dialog.close();
                });

                final Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
                cancelButton.setOnAction(close -> dialog.close());

                dialogVbox.getChildren().add(updateButton);
                dialogVbox.getChildren().add(cancelButton);

                Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogVbox, 400, 350);
                dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
                dialog.show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Problem occured", e);
            }
        });
        return mainUpdateButton;
    }

    private void restartStopwatch(Button button) {

        final Timer restartTimer = new Timer();
        final TimerTask updateRestartTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            int time = 5;

            @Override
            public void run() {

                button.setText("Updated. Restarting in: " + time + " Seconds...");
                time--;
                if (time <= 0) {
                    restartTimer.cancel();
                    new UpdateChecker().restartApplication();
                }
            }
        };
        restartTimer.schedule(updateRestartTimerTask, 0, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting the exact behavior you describe: it really should throw an `IllegalStateException` as you are calling `button.setText(...)` from a background thread.

Use a `Timeline`:

```
private void restartStopwatch(Button button) {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        final int timeRemaining = 5 - i ;
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(i), 
            e -> button.setText("Updated. Restarting in: " + timeRemaining + " Seconds..."));
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
    }
    timeline.setOnFinished(e -> new UpdateChecker().restartApplication());
    timeline.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Task (Wich is a Background JavaFX Thread) that handle the countdown and place the text on your button:

```
final Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            //Countdown code here
            return null;
        }
    };

new Thread(task).start();
```

You can read more about Tasks in the official documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html